# Не деплоится spring приложение на heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku

Вот ссылка на репозиторий  https://github.com/CRIPS0/tkrsite
Не понимаю в чем ошибка первый раз деплою

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

новая
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очевидно на heroku не поддерживается java 11. Точно, по умолчанию, java 8 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions. Читайте, там написано, как указать другую версию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Heroku по-умолчанию устанавливается Java 8, в вашем проекте требуется Java 11.

[Как задать версию Java на Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version):

Создать файл `system.properties` и добавить в него строку `java.runtime.version=`, где после равно номер требуемой версии из [списка поддерживаемых](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions).

Comment: возможно не из-за этого проблема @Nyuhnyash

Comment: @ИванКандаков Ты поменял версию и проблема осталась?

Comment: Да @Nyuhnyash(((

Comment: @ИванКандаков, а какая на этот раз ошибка?

Comment: сейчас я взял проект по проще https://github.com/CRIPS0/notesEDIT33, с java 1.8 ошибку в основном вопросе скину

Comment: @ИванКандаков, на этот раз ошибка уже [в коде](https://github.com/CRIPS0/notesEDIT33/blob/921214e60a675df446205569927f6a42a6385549/src/main/java/com/IK/notes/Controllers/MainController.java#L86) в методе `orElseThrow()`.

Comment: я запустил первый сайт который скидывал на java 1.8, спасибо тебе большое что ты существуешь

Comment: Со  вторым проектом буду сам разбиратсья